# MySQL year interval that Includes the entire month from the previous year

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have MySQL condition that grabs a time interval from now back x number of months.  Typically, this will be set to 13 months so you can compare the current month to that of last year.

```
'created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL ' . $timeInterval . ' MONTH)'
```

So for example last January compared to this January, but I'd like to include all of the previous years month.  So instead of January 20, 2015 to January 20, 2016 I would have January 01, 2015 to the current date in January this year until February 1st.

Comment: Please clarify your question to include sample dates and desired results.

Comment: Did not understand what you need. I think you may get lost into that intervals. Try to explain it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `DATE_FORMAT` to make it quick and easy, replace the "day" part of the date with a constant. Then subtract your number of months...

```
... t.created > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL ? MONTH
```

---

As a demonstration of what is returned by that expression, we can test it using a simple SELECT statement:

```
SELECT NOW(), DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 12 MONTH

NOW()                DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 12 MONTH  
-------------------  -------------------------------------------------
2016-01-27 21:01:02  2015-01-01
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Are you sure you want a "greater than" comparison, rather than a "greater than or equal to" comparison **`>=`** ?

There are other approaches to generating that date value to compare to. You could use `DATE(NOW())` or `CURDATE()` to return the current date with no time component.

And use the `DAY()` function to get the numeric value of the current day, and then subtract that (minus 1) as a number of days. For example, something like this:

```
 >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL DAY(NOW())-1 DAY - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
```

That seems messier and more complicated. I think it's easier to understand stuffing in the `'-01'` as the day part.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this looks great, but I can't seem to get it work is this what it should look like in my the where clause:
`Application.created > NOW(), DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 13 MONTH`?  I'm sure it isn't, but this isn't my strength

Comment: Remove that first **`NOW(),`** from your WHERE clause. I included that in the `SELECT` statement as a demonstration.  Just compare your column to the second expression, as shown in the code example *before* the Demonstration:. I think you want to replace the `?` with a `12`.)

Comment: Thanks, that's great.  I've already found another use for this. Never thought to set the date format with a constant.

Comment: Yah I definitely meant to put >= thanks for catching that.

Comment: Is it possible this wouldn't work for MySQL 5.5?  I'm running MySQL 5.6 locally which comes with XAMPP, but the server is not only Linux, but is running MySQL 5.5 and it looks like this doesn't work on the production server.  Only locally.  Would the version render dates differently?  If I run the same query without the Application.created statement I get results, otherwise the result set is empty, but there are definitely applications within this time interval.

Answer (score 0):

```
created > str_to_date(concat(year(now())-1, '-01-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Or if you need not all previous year:

```
select str_to_date(concat(year(now())-1, '-', month(now()),'-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```